# Cordova localStorage data recovery

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have an Ionic app that was side-loaded onto an Android device that kept data in localStorage. The usual mechanism for syncing the data back to our server has failed, and cannot be manually triggered from within the app. Recovering this data is important to a client. Is there any way to access this data? Can it be accessed through a different app that shares an ID with the original? Can the JS in the original be modified in place so that it posts out the data to a rest endpoint? Does Android keep localStorage on the filesystem in a way that is accessible? I have physical access to the device in question.

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to inspect the app using chrome:inspect. You could then see the contents of localStorage

Comment: It was built with `--release`, so no connecting to the inspector.

Comment: This might help: http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2012/07/reading-data-stored-in-localstroage-by.html  Would installing a new version work? I think localStorage persists across different versions so you would be able to create a new version that posts the data for you. You should test this locally before trying it.